# Cannot remote upload through openload API [PHP - curl]

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to upload a file using the openload API that can be found [here](https://openload.co/api).

When I upload some file I always get a [JSON response](https://jsonblob.com/7f85eff1-82cd-11e7-a52a-f5b8771f5891) of success (code: 200):

Unfortunately when I check the file status (using both API and website) it tells me that there was an error in upload. Here the [JSON response](https://jsonblob.com/a481e436-82ca-11e7-9d06-6fbd6b71ed1e) (code 200):

Here is how I send the request. Where's the error? I tried using both the urlencode function and not.

```
$user = "...";
$psw = "...";
$link = urlencode("https://google.com/favicon.ico");
$url = "https://api.openload.co/1/remotedl/add?login=$user&key=$psw&url=$link";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
```

EDIT: Switched to https and added `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true`, still no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting a http 301 redirect while using curl

```
http://google.com/favicon.ico
```

to

```
https://www.google.com/favicon.ico
```

If that case curl option CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION might help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I changed the code but I still have no success.I really can't see where's the problem.

Comment: Can you please share the downloaded file content ? It looks like you have downoaded something ("id": "12312312", "bytes_total": "231",)